# rxjs `toArray` is not working as expected

Tags: rxjs

I tried to de-duplicate the sent arrays and then merge them into arrays

```
import { from, BehaviorSubject, distinct, switchMap, toArray } from "rxjs";

let list$ = new BehaviorSubject([1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 5]);

list$.pipe(
  switchMap((e) => from(e)),
  distinct(),
  toArray()
).subscribe(console.log);
```

expected result:

```
BehaviorSubject -> [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 5]
switchMap       -> 1 2 3 2 3 5
distinct        -> 1 2 3 5
toArray         -> [1, 2, 3, 5]
console.log     -> [1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Actually did not receive any value in console.log, why is this and how can I work as expected

```
"rxjs": "^7.2.0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if the source does not stop after the first notification, I assume that it will continue emit other arrays and that you want to filter the duplicates on each array emitted. In other words, if the `list$` of your example emits first `[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 5]` and then `[3, 2, 1, 6, 6, 6,]` what you want to log are 2 arrays, `[1, 2, 3, 5]` and `[3, 2, 1, 6]`.

If my assumption is right, than the solution could be the following

```
list$.pipe(
  concatMap((e) => from(e).pipe(
    distinct(),
    toArray()
  )),
).subscribe(console.log);
```

The trick here is that each `from(e)` stream will `complete` when there are no more elements in the array. Therefore, since it `complete`s, the `toArray` operator can actually work.

Answer (score 2):

toArray only emits once the source observable completes.

The following should work as expected.

```ts
list$.pipe(
  take(1),
  switchMap(e => e),
  distinct(),
  toArray()
).subscribe(console.log);
```

---

If what you really want to do is filter unique values of an array, then RxJS's unique operator might be overkill. I wouldn't bother turning your array into a stream. Just filter the array.

```ts
list$.pipe(
  map(a => [...new Set(a)])
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my source will not stop after sending it once. Is there an operator that replaces `toArray`

Comment: Hey @januwa, If that's the case, I don't think you need RxJS to do your uniqueness filtering. See my update above.

Answer (score 1):

If the only requirement is to remove duplicates, you're better off handling it using vaniall JS. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229821/6513921

We'll take the shortest solution without any regards to performance: `uniq = [...new Set(array)];`

You could then write a custom RxJS operator to include it in the pipe with other operators.

```js
const { BehaviorSubject, from } = rxjs;
const { map, switchMap } = rxjs.operators;

const uniqueArray = (obs$) => {
  return (obs$) => {
    return obs$.pipe(
      map(arr => [...new Set(arr)])
    );
  };
};

const sub = new BehaviorSubject([1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 5]);

sub.asObservable().pipe(
  uniqueArray()
).subscribe(console.log);

sub.next([6, 3, 1, 6, 7, 1, 1]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.2.2/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`scan` could do the trick.

```
list$.pipe(
  switchMap((e) => from(e)),
  distinct(),
  scan((acc, curr) => [...acc, curr], []),
).subscribe(console.log);
// will print: [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 5]
```

You could insert `debounceTime` in the pipe, if you need less emissions:

```
list$.pipe(
  switchMap((e) => from(e)),
  distinct(),
  scan((acc, curr) => [...acc, curr], []),
  debounceTime(0)
).subscribe(console.log); // will print [1, 2, 3, 5]
```